# looking to filter on dataframe based on another

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

First Df contains dates and attendance with names

```
date            1        2     3   .....50
2021-10-01    jhohn     bob    jerry.....
2021-10-02    Ram       jhohn  bob    jerry
Second df contains
date        name  activity_info(multiple columns)
2021-10-01  john  fgfhfgh
2021-10-01  Ram   dfsdfsdf
```

I want to filter out data for the elements not present in first Data frame on that particular date.
for instance Ram is not in 2021-10-01. that has to be removed. the number of columns may vary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can melt first data and inner join with second data:

```
df1.melt('date', value_name='name').merge(df2, on=['date','name'])
```

Output:

```
         date variable   name activity_info
0  2021-10-01        1  jhohn       fgfhfgh
```